# Is there a way to write a module test function in nim that is excluded when imported

Tags: module

So I have recently been experimenting with the [nim](https://nim-lang.org/) programming language and I'm actually enjoying it quite a bit.

I am writing a module that handles certain io features of my project and I want to write a function in the module to run a few tests if I where to compile just the module file.

I know that nim supports the `when` keyword which basically acts as a compiler filter to exclude certain code at compile time and I am wondering if there is some feature in nim that lets me check if a given file is the "main" compiled file

does nim have something like python's `if __name__ == "__main__"`

or am I stuck just commenting out/ignoring the test functions?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I finally found it after even more digging. Apparently nim does support this. It has a compile time (constant/variable) `isMainModule: bool = false` that is set to true only when the code in the given file is the main file to your program